# hibernate/jpa double OneToOne Bidirectional Relationship to one entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, orm

I have the following structure that I can't figure out how to put in the correct hibernate mapping.

```
public class Company{
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "details_x")
    private Details detailsX;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "details_y")
    private Details detailsY;
}
```

and

```
public class Details{
    ....
    private Type type; //Enum that could be x or y

    @OneToOne
    private Company company;
}
```

Company has exactly on details for x and one for y. A details can only be used by one company in either x or y.
Database wise I'm think the best set-up is to have 2 columns on tbl_company reference the Pk of Details. 
But this results in the relation from Details to Company not working.

Anyone any suggestions on how to best map this?

Edit: added type to Details

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `mappedBy` property which will say that i am not the owner like below.

```
public class Details{
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "detailsX", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
                  fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Company company;
}
```

Comment: This only works then for detailsX not for detailsY, the problem I'm having it is one of these 2